# Shouldn't there be no tearing and gluing in deformation in topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

From what I understood about deformation in topology is that there should be no tearing and gluing.

[image]

But from the textbook Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher, why could the sum $B_1+B'_1$ be deformable to $B_2$? Does that involve gluing and ungluing?

Thanks.

Comment: This still really isn't the full definition of a loop, nor a path.  A *path* in a topological space $X$ is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to X$,  and a *loop* in a path with $f(0)=f(1)$.

Comment: To me it looks like.. at  a four road junction if you want a pair of roads joined, then  there are two types/ possibilities: 1) Join adjacent roads with a drive-by at the nearest point $ B_0,$  and, 2) Join opposite roads by a fly-over intersection at.$B_2.$ The first choice is quite disjunct and makes no knot at all, while the second choice makes a proper knot with $A$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the picture is taking place in the ambient space $X$ and $\gamma, \gamma' : [0,1] \to X$ are the loops based at $x_0$ labelled $B_1$ and $B_1'$ respectively, then $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = x_0$ and $\gamma'(0) = \gamma'(1) = x_0$. Their concatenation is $\gamma\ast\gamma' : I \to X$ given by

$$\gamma\ast\gamma'(t) = \begin{cases}
\gamma(2t) & 0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{2}\\
\gamma'(1-2t) & \frac{1}{2} < t \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$

Note that $\gamma\ast\gamma'(t) = x_0$ when $t = 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1$. Homotopy of loops is relative to the subset $\{0, 1\}$. That is, when you deform the loop $\gamma\ast\gamma'$, you only need to keep its values at $t = 0$ and $t = 1$ fixed, all the others can vary. In particular, as you deform the loop, its value at $t = \frac{1}{2}$ may not stay fixed at $x_0$ as is illustrated in the second picture.